# d3 - hover on legend to highlight the respective data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Successfully created a heatmap using d3.

Here's the [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/bP8J8/1/).

I have some basic idea on using d3's `mouseover` events. But now I wanted move a step ahead.

This is what I'm looking for. When I hover on a legend, I wanted the hovered legend's respective data to be highlighted in the chart.

Can someone help me to achieve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not binding the data to the legend, which makes this task a bit more difficult, but you can still do it fairly easily. The idea is to assign a class defined by the fill color to the `rect` elements and then select accordingly in the mouseover handler. The code looks like this.

```
// for the rectangles
.attr("class", function(d) {  
  return "hour bordered " + "color-" + colorScale(d.value).substring(1);
})

// for the legend
.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {
  svg.selectAll("rect.color-" + colors[i].substring(1)).style("stroke", "blue");
})
.on("mouseout", function(d, i) {
  svg.selectAll("rect.color-" + colors[i].substring(1)).style("stroke", "white");
});
```

Complete example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bP8J8/2/).

Comment: Many thanks to you. At least now I got a clear understanding on how it working.

Comment: @charantej You should post a separate question about this with a complete example that demonstrates the problem.