# what is the best way to update pie chart on hover of bars in a bar chart - d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With the help of this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21235173/d3-hover-on-legend-to-highlight-the-respective-data) I've got a some flexibility on mouse over events in d3.

And I've managed to show some values on hovering on the bars.

Now that if I'm creating a `pie` chart and if I wanted to update that pie chart on hovering the bars of the bar chart. What will be the best way for me to include the pie chart data to the existing data in this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/prDzK/) and how can i retrieve that data for the pie chart?

I'm looking for something like [**this**](http://trends.truliablog.com/vis/tru247/).

In the above example if you hover of the `rect`. Bar chart on the right bottom corner gets updated.

I couldn't find any code given for that. But found this in the [**page source**](http://trends.truliablog.com/vis/tru247/tru247.js?v=1.01).

Any suggestions can be helpful for me to achieve this.

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like crossfilter

http://square.github.io/crossfilter/

#### UPDATE

The idea is that you update the pie chart with when you get a click on the master chart (bar chart).

Let's say your data looks something like:

```
var ds = [
    { key: 'A', values: [1,2,3,4], sum: function () { return d3.sum(this.values); } },
    { key: 'B', values: [20, 30, 40], sum: function () { return d3.sum(this.values); } },
    { key: 'C', values: [100, 200, 300], sum: function () { return d3.sum(this.values); } }
];
```

And you have a function to create/update the pie like:

```
function updatePie(svg, data, radius) {
    var color = d3.scale.category20c();
    var arc = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius);
    var formattedData = d3.layout.pie()(data);
    var slice = svg.selectAll('.slice')
        .data(formattedData);

    slice.enter()
        .append('path')
        .attr('fill', function(d, i) { return color(i); })
        .attr('class', 'slice')
        .attr('d', arc);

    slice
        .attr('d', arc);

    slice.exit()
        .remove();
}
```

Now on the click handler for your bar chart you do

```
var clickHandler = function (dataPoint) {
    updatePie(svg, dataPoint.values, r);
};
```

Here's a working example using just list for the master (replacing the bar chart) but the idea is the same:

http://jsfiddle.net/jaimedp/q45z6/1/

Hope this helps

Comment: I can even use [**this**](http://nickqizhu.github.io/dc.js/). But I wanted to do it only using `d3`.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually know how to update the `pie` chart. But the only place where I was stuck is the data format. After seeing the data you've prepared to pass to the pie chart. I got a clear picture of it now. Any other way can pass the data like if the `[1,2,3,4]` was in 4 different columns?

Comment: Can you say me what's that `ev` you've used in the `clickHandler` function.

Comment: ev will contain the data point bound to the element you click on. ie. if you click on a bar of a bar chart, you will get the data for that bar... Changed the name to dataPoint to make it clearer

Comment: Any documentation link i could find for crossfilter other than link you've provided? Because I couldn't get anything clear on crossfilter.